# Add marker to google maps v2, where the map is added programmatically

Tags: java, android, google-maps

So I am trying to implement google maps v2 for my android application. I have successfully added a map to my application using the code below. I have also added the code for the layout. I dont want to change this implementation as I have a tabular view and the map is one of the tabs. Do you have any suggestions on what I can do.

```
    mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();   
    android.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, mMapFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp" >
    </FrameLayout>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a marker like this:

```
mMapFragment.getMap().addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(0, 0))
        .title("Hello world"));
```